# Checking if server process is listening on domain socket or not

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix, client-server

I'm writting client-server programs, that using unix domain socket for communicating between two  sides.
The requirement is:

1. Server opens an abstract socket on a given address, then listen on that. By some triggers, server can stop listening on that.
2. Client has to monitor that Server is listening on given address path or not

   - if server **is listening on socket** then send a register request to server
   - if server **close the socket** then do some action cleaning up...

To check the server is listening or not, my solution is:

Periodically **create a socket** and **connect to server address path**, if succeed, then means that server is listening, and vice versa for any case of error.

But the solution seems to be cpu-consuming if checking interval is too short.

***Then my question is:*** do we have any method like registering some callback to system, and get the notification whenever some process starts/stops listening on a given address? or some other better suggestion...??

Many thanks,

Comment: What is the interval that you are using ? The checks that you describe will (normally) take small fraction of a second, and with proper delay will not result in lot of CPU ? What is the requirement (to detect server up/down) ?

Comment: The interval depends on speed of on/off of server. In my case it takes 5ms, and I can see, in the IDLE state the client constantly checks for server status, then it always stay on top of task manager. Sometimes is 1% CPU time.

Comment: You can always increase the client delay, and reduce CPU. For the case of detecting the server going down, you can keep the connection open, and do a read. It will fail when the server closes the connection, with no CPU load.

Comment: I already tried with case of interval is 1 second, but for case server goes down and up very fast, it won't be able to see the change. I can provide some workaround to solve this problem, but I still hope to have a better method for this.

Comment: If you can keep client connection open, and wait for the read to fail, you will have instant detection of server going down, regardless of the time to go up.

Comment: I already thought about this, but we have to keep all the connections for every client from server side. It needs a lot of modification for this approach. but I think I need to rethink on this method. thanks.

Comment: Assuming you can change reverse code, consider adding a request to get the server instance I’d, which can be concatenation of server start time+pid. Client can compare I’d, with previously known I’d, and perform registration if the I’d is different

Comment: Yes, thanks, it is an idea as well, I already think about similar approach like creating a semaphore, and whenever server is on, it increases the semaphore value, and client can observe that value to get notification. I still in search for an ideal solution!